# HTML5 rotate animation - How to show "the other side of the coin"?

Tags: css, html, animation, css-animations

Considering [this JSFiddle rotation example](https://jsfiddle.net/194288aw/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="coin">
    <div class="face heads">
      Hey!
    </div>
    <div class="face tails">
      Ho!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes rotation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 360deg);
  }
}

.container {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.coin {
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  animation-name: rotation;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-duration: 2.5s;
}

.face {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.heads {
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 2;
}

.tails {
  background-color: gray;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

As you can see, the proverbial `.coin` consists of two `.face`s, represented by two overlapping `div`s with different `z-index`.

Shouldn't the animation render the `.tails` face when reaching 50% of the keyframe, since the whole `.coin` is being rotated around the Y axis?
Or am I just expecting too much from HTML5? Or am I simply doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance for any clarification!

Comment: @Paulie_D Good point, thanks. I edited the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to do some research and, with the help of [**David Walsh- CSS Flip**](https://davidwalsh.name/css-flip)

```css
@keyframes rotation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 360deg);
  }
}
.container {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  perspective: 1000;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
.coin {
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  animation-name: rotation;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-duration: 2.5s;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.face {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.heads {
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.tails {
  background-color: gray;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="coin">
    <div class="face heads">
      Hey!
    </div>
    <div class="face tails">
      Ho!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep. Those are the properties I was looking for. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Is there a way get the same effect, but actually using images? I followed the same tutorial, but if I replace the text with images, I don't get the effect, only one side is displayed